# How to get data from Array in android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I want to get data from array in android. I give array bellow. tell me how to get data from this array in android. I get this array from Parse.

```
[
  {
    "name": "ajino motto",
    "qty": 30,
    "unit": "Gms"
  },
  {
    "name": "cobbige",
    "qty": 20,
    "unit": "Gms"
  },
  {
    "name": "salt",
    "qty": 0,
    "unit": "Gms"
  }
]
```

Comment: if your array is from a string use Gson, http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-json-tutorial-create-and-parse-json-data.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This Way

```
List<JSONObject> jsobj = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

            jsobj = CommanClass.ParseObject_RecieptMaster
                    .getList(MainScreen.key_ingredientlist);

            for (int i = 0; i < jsobj.size(); i++) {
                Log.e("in the For loop ", ": : ::111111 : " + jsobj.get(i));

                JSONObject arr1 = new JSONObject((Map) jsobj.get(i)); // jsobj.get(i);
                Log.e("in the For loop ", ": : ::111111 : " + arr1);
                try {
                    Log.e("in the For loop ",
                            ": : ::111111 : " + arr1.getString("name"));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
```

its completed work in my Application.

Answer (score 3):

```
String[] list;
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    list[i]= array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonPrimitive("name").getAsString();
}
```

Comment: Answers should be more detailed. Currently this is a low-quality answer.